# LinearLayout not working when creating text view

Tags: java, android

I'm facing a problem where the code works fine but my text (textview) doesn't appear in the linearlayout which I'm not sure why

this is my code:

```
LinearLayout linearScrollableMin = findViewById(R.id.linearScrollableMin);
    TextView tryingTV1 = new TextView(this);
    tryingTV1.setBackgroundColor(000);
    tryingTV1.setText("1");
    tryingTV1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ((LinearLayout) linearScrollableMin).addView(tryingTV1);
```

and a picture of the component tree
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXuBH.png)

Comment: Could you add more information about what is not working. At the moment your code seems to work and the text view is displayed. You may need to add more code to your question to better show your problem.

Comment: yup just edited it

Answer (score 0):

The text view is being displayed but it is being pushed offscreen by the first scrollview. If you reduce the width of the first scrollview you will be able to see the text view

Comment: I tried to and even tried to delete the first and last scroll views but it is no use